# Having the last register from a query in sql that use a group by clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I've got this set of registers (just an example) after ordering by the first 3 columns:

```
value_A     value_B     value_C     ID     date
1           2           3           YVIR     29/08/2015
1           2           3           ANTE     27/04/2015
1           2           3           REGO     20/02/2015
```

I need to get as a final result:

```
 value_A     value_B     value_C     ID       date
    1           2           3        REGO     29/08/2015
```

In other words, I need to get, after ordering the result by the date field, the most recent date but at the same time the oldest ID in the list.

I've been trying to do this with the group by clause:

```
select 
value_A, value_B, value_C, min(ID), max(date) -- or max(ID)
from table
order by value_A, value_B, value_C
```

But in the field ID I'm getting the wrong result because this value is been associated with the alphabetic order.

In access this query involves the function LAST, but in SQL I have not found a good way to perform this. And I am asking because I have seen some possible solution but almost all of them involving the UNION operation, but my problem is, this table can have more than 350.000 registers.

This table is update by some one else, I just can access the information and use it as a source.

Comment: "in the field ID I'm getting ..." - What "field ID"? I can't find one in your datasets.

Comment: I think a SQLFiddle with some additional example rows would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating 2 queries, one for the max(user), and one for the min(date)?
Since you want just one record, seemingly, at the end, you can put them together after.

Comment: thanks @nepdev for your reply. That is precisely what I want to avoid, the DBA does not seem to be happy by using 2 queries, maybe becuase this table sometimes can reach a huge number of records and is used for preparing different reports.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but something like this might work:

```
select t1.value_A, t1.value_B, t1.value_C, max(t1.date), max(t2.user)
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.value_A = t2.value_A and t1.value_B = ...
where ...
group by t1.value_A, t1.value_B, t1.value_C
having t2.date = max(t2.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get, after ordering the result by the date field, the most
>   recent date but at the same time the oldest ID in the list.

So get the most recent row by date, and use a subquery for the user (which you seem to be calling ID here) column:

```
SELECT TOP 1 value_A, value_B, value_C, 
(SELECT TOP 1 user FROM table ORDER BY [date] ASC) AS user,
[date]
FROM table
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (requires SQL Server 2012 or later):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     value_A, value_B, value_C,
     oldest_user = FIRST_VALUE([user]) OVER (PARTITION BY value_A, value_B, value_C ORDER BY [date]),
     newest_date = LAST_VALUE([date])  OVER (PARTITION BY value_A, value_B, value_C ORDER BY [date] RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM table
```